# Time Inaccuracy or Inefficient Code?

Tags: python, datetime, time, stopwatch

I'm currently working on a program that will display the amount of time that has passed since a specific point. A stopwatch, if you will.

I've finally gotten my code working, but as it turns out, it's not very accurate. It falls behind very quickly, being 1 or even 2 seconds off within just the first 10 seconds of running, I'm not completely sure why this is.

```
#   Draw
def draw():
    stdscr.erase()
    stdscr.border()

    #   Debugging
    if debug:
        stdscr.addstr(5 , 3, "running  : %s " % running )
        stdscr.addstr(6 , 3, "new      : %s " % new )
        stdscr.addstr(7 , 3, "pureNew  : %s " % pureNew )
        stdscr.addstr(8 , 3, "paused   : %s " % paused )
        stdscr.addstr(9 , 3, "complete : %s " % complete )
        stdscr.addstr(10, 3, "debug    : %s " % debug )

    if running:
        stdscr.addstr(1, 1, ">", curses.color_pair(8))
        stdscr.addstr(1, 3, t.strftime( "%H:%M.%S", t.gmtime( timeElapsedTotal ) ) )

    elif not running:
        if new and pureNew:
            stdscr.addstr(1, 1, ">", curses.color_pair(5))
            stdscr.addstr(1, 3, t.strftime( "%H:%M.%S", timeNone ) )
        elif paused:
            stdscr.addstr(1, 3, t.strftime( "%H:%M.%S", t.gmtime( timeElapsedTotal ) ), curses.color_pair(1) )
            stdscr.addstr(1, 1, ">", curses.color_pair(3))
        else:
            stdscr.addstr(1, 1, ">", curses.color_pair(5))
            stdscr.addstr(1, 3, t.strftime( "%H:%M.%S", timeNone ) )

    stdscr.redrawwin()
    stdscr.refresh()
    return

    #   Calculations
def calc():
    global timeElapsedTotal
    if running:
        timeElapsedTotal = t.clock() - timeStart
    return

    #   Main Loop
while True:
    #   Get input from the user
    kInput = stdscr.getch()

    #   If q is pressed we close the program
    if kInput == ord('q'):
        endProg()

    #   If d is pressed we toggle 'debug' mode
    elif kInput == ord('d'):
        debug = not debug

    #   If s is pressed we stop the current run
    elif kInput == ord('s'):
        running = False
        new = True

    #   If spacebar is pressed and we are ready for a new run,
    #       we start a new run
    elif kInput == ord(' ') and new:
        running = not running
        new = not new
        pureNew = False
        timeStart = t.clock()

    #   If p is pressed and we are in the middle of a run,
    #       we pause the run
    elif kInput == ord('p') and not new:
        running = not running
        paused = not paused
        timeStart = t.clock() - timeStart

    calc()
    draw()
```

The above code is, as far as I am aware, working as intended. I'm not sure if the lag is coming from `time.clock()` or if it's simply my inefficient code. Is this the kind of work that I would need to use threads for?

I did a bit of googling and saw others talking about other functions in the time module but none of those worked any better for me.

Let me know if this isn't enough information or I made a simple mistake.

Comment: `time.clock` means different things on different operating systems - very annoying, but there it is. On linux its elapsed execution time, not wall clock time and shouldn't be used for counting seconds.

Comment: @tdelaney Ok that makes sense. Do you know of any good alternatives? Will I run into this same issue using the datetime module, or is that the next step here?

Comment: I don't know if there is a more modern way to fix this but back in the day I would check whether I was running on linux (high res wall clock is time.time()) or windows (high res wall clock is time.clock) via `platform.system()` and choose a clock from there.

Comment: Let me know if changing the clock works.

Comment: @tdelaney Worked like a charm. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as it turns out the solution was as simple as changing from `time.clock()` to `time.time()` as suggested by *tdelaney*.

Looks like I need to more thoroughly read up on modules as I use them. Thanks for the wisdom.